# Symfony 4 Service "Call to member function on null"

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection

Using Symfony 4 and php7.2 Trying to use LoginFormAuthenticator (https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-security) and updating to Symfony 4 (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html)
No matter what I do, it appears that the dependency injection is not working for me.
From documentation it seems simple: use autowire in config/services.yaml, put use statement for service in LoginFormAuthenticator.php file, put Type Hint argument in constructor

```
public function _construct(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory)
{
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
}

public function supports(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($this->formFactory);
}
```

The var_dump gives NULL

Trying to call a method on $this->formFactory gives error message:

> Call to member function xyz on null

Tried autowire and tried using arguments without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe use the actual constructor `__construct` with 2 underscores? You could have added an echo to see if the constructor was even being called as a first step.

Comment: Ahh. Stupid newbie error--my bad. Many thanks as I have spent days on this. Tried putting var_dump and echo in (supposed) constructor, but got no response so put in a function I knew was called.

Answer (score 0):

your construct function should have two `_`  ,now it has one so it won't run and  `$formFactory` is null, In such cases you should first check your construct run

Comment: Hi, why you answer an old question ?

Comment: Hi,because i have similar problem in 4.3 symfony